# Applications of differential calculus: Optimisation

Tags: derivatives, applications, maxima-minima

A large industrial water tank is made of galvanised steel. It is in the shape of a closed cylinder and has volume of 216000 litres.

The tank has radius $r$ metres and height $h$ metres.

a) Show that the surface area, $Sm^2$, of the tank is given by: $$S=2\pi r^2 + \frac{432}{r}$$

b) i) Find the value of $r$ which minimises the surface area of the cylinder.
   ii) Determine the minimum surface area.

I was able to complete part a. On part bi I differentiated(to find the maximum and minimum values of the function)but I do not know how to solve the differentiated equation to get values for $r$.
$$S=2\pi r^2 + \frac{432}{r}$$

$$\frac{dS}{dr} = 4\pi r -\frac{432}{r^2}$$

Any help on how to solve this equation would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must equate it to zero, and find the value of $r$.

$$r = {\left(\dfrac{108}{\pi}\right)}^{\frac{1}{3}}$$

If you find $S''$ you'll see it is **greater than zero**, hence **minima**.

Comment: Sorry I didn't add it in, I did know to equate it to zero. However from that point I don't know how to rearrange to get a value for r. Could you show me how you got that value for r?

Comment: Cross multiply and take $r$ on one side.